# Int vs Double in assembly

Tags: c++, c, gcc, x86, reverse-engineering

Why GCC compiler adds this three lines when using double and don't when there is Int?

---

With int:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    int i = 1;
}
```

==>

```
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 1
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

---

With double:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    double i = 1;
}
```

==>

```
main:
        lea     ecx, [esp+4]            // This three lines
        and     esp, -8                 //  ...
        push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]       //  ...
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    ecx
        sub     esp, 20
        fld1
        fstp    QWORD PTR [ebp-16]
        mov     eax, 0
        add     esp, 20
        pop     ecx
        pop     ebp
        lea     esp, [ecx-4]
        ret
```

Similar happens when using pointers, for example, int *s = new int(4);

Can you explain why this happens, and why not always?

Comment: If you don't use the `-O3` switch the compiler generates code that can be redundant or nonsense (though still correct)

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just learning :)

Comment: Is this C or C++? They are different languages and there will likely be differet code generated for function entry/exit.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Not nonsense. Just superfluous. But often better comprehensible by beginners and easier to debug. In general it is best to compile with `-Og` for debugging, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of a `double` in automatic scope (on the stack), the extra code aligns the stack frame at an even 8 byte boundary, so that the `double` variable is stored at a memory address with suitable alignment. The stack pointer, when entering the function, is not guaranteed to be aligned on an even 8-byte boundary, and the compiler adds the extra code to make it so.

That's what the `and esp, -8` does. -8 is 0xFFFFFFF8. This clears the last 3 bits of `esp`, using `and`, making it point to an even 8 byte boundary memory address, adjusting it down (the stack grows from high to low memory addresses).

Comment: Sure, that's what the code does. But why does it do that for `double` but not for `int`? (Serious question, not trolling: I haven't looked at code generation issues in a long time...)

Comment: On x86, `double` is a 64-bit type and requires 8-byte alignment, but the ABI does not require that the stack be 8-byte aligned. The same thing happens for `long long`, BTW, since it's also an 8-byte type. It isn't necessary for `int` because that's just a 4-byte type, and the stack pointer is guaranteed to be 4-byte aligned.